# c# - executing event without it happening

Tags: c#, events

How could I execute an event, without it actually happening?

For example, how would I execute a `button1_Click()` event in code, without clicking the button?

The problem is that I have a `WebClient`, which doewnloads lists of files.
 Each time it finishes downloading a file it executes a `DownloadFileCompleted` event, which then downloads the next file.

However, some files aren't downloaded (all in plan), so the event is not executed. How could I execute it?
Thanks

Comment: *please* use paragraphs in your questions, it's almost impossible to read a block of text

Comment: How do you know *when* to execute the event?

Comment: I have a list of file URL-s, with a boolean value for either download or dont. I then check before downloading.

Comment: Are you able to provide any source code? This may be as straight forward as explicitly calling the method, but without source code it's difficult to predict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just insert all code present in the event handler in a separate function, like

```
private void button1_click(...)
{
    func(...)
}


public void func(...)
{
    //even handler code
}
```

and if you don't what to raise an  event, or can't, just call

```
func(...)
```

I personally against calling event handler esplicitly, but prefer this approach. **To me** seems more clear code structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could just feed it empty values and call it like a normal function (after all, it is a normal function that simply needs a sender and the appropriate event arguments).
E.g.

```
button_click(new object(), new System.EventArgs());
```

Those are the normal events for a standard GUI button, your button might need different events. This approach works, if you only need your button to detect the click and don't want to use the event arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Controls often have the ability to raise an event e.g. [Button.PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick%28VS.80%29.aspx) in your case

Answer (score 0):

button1_Click() is just a method, so you can execute it even if you bound it to an event.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the code out of your event handler and into a function.

You can then call this function from the both the event and any other method you need to trigger it.

So instead of:

```
private void button1_Click()
{
    //do something
}
```

You have:

```
private void button1_Click()
{
    doSomething();
}

public void doSomething()
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Name of your Button is *button1*, you can raise the click-event by following line of code:

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Or like others have said, put your logic in a separate method and call the method when needed.